# Error detection code for 33 bytes, detecting bit flipped in first 32 bytes

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashcode, pearson, error-detection

Could you please suggest an error detection scheme for detecting 
one possible bit flip in the first 32 bytes of a 33-byte message using 
no more than 8 bits of additional data?

Could Pearson hashing be a solution?

Comment: Do you need to *detect* whether a single bit was flipped, or identify *which* of the bits was flipped?

Comment: I only need to detect that flip occurred.

Answer (score 7):

Detecting a single bit-flip in any message requires only one extra bit, independent of the length of the message: simply xor together all the bits in the message and tack that on the end. If any single bit flips, the parity bit at the end won't match up.

If you're asking to detect which bit flipped, that can't be done, and a simple argument shows it: the extra eight bits can represent up to 256 classes of 32-byte messages, but the zero message and the 256 messages with one on bit each must all be in different classes. Thus, there are 257 messages which must be distinctly classified, and only 256 classes.

Comment: ...though nine extra bits per 32 bytes is already enough to correct single bit-flips! Use one bit for parity, and use the other eight bits to xor together the addresses of the on bits.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but could you please explain what do you mean by xoring together the "addresses"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @robel, well, for example, for the four-bit message 0101, addresses 1 and 3 are on, so you would xor together 01 and 11 to get 10. But it turns out the simple protocol I described doesn't quite work after all; you need to include the parity bit when doing the address bits, and that parity bit puts the number of addresses juuuuuust over the eight-bit limit. Dang.

Answer (score 5):

You can detect one bit flip with just one extra bit in any length message (as stated by @Daniel Wagner). The parity bit can, simply put, indicate whether the total number of 1-bits is odd or even. Obviously, if the number of bits that are wrong is even, then the parity bit will fail, so you cannot detect 2-bit errors.

Now, for a more accessible understanding of why you can't error-correct 32 bytes (256 bits) with just 8 bits, please read about the [Hamming code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) (like used in ECC memory). Such a scheme uses special error-correcting parity bits (henceforth called "EC parity") that only encode the parity of a subset of the total number of bits. For every `2^m - 1` total bits, you need to use `m` EC bits. These represent each possible different mask following the pattern "x bits on, x bits off" where `x` is a power of 2. Thus, the larger the number of bits at once, the better the data/parity bit ratio you get. For example, 7 total bits would allow encoding only 4 data bits after losing 3 EC bits, but 31 total bits can encode 26 data bits after losing 5 EC bits.

Now, to really understand this probably will take an example. Consider the following sets of masks. The first two rows are to be read top down, indicating the bit number (the "Most Significant Byte" I've labeled MSB):

```
  MSB                                LSB
   |                                  |
   v                                  v
   33222222 22221111 11111100 0000000|0
   10987654 32109876 54321098 7654321|0
   -------- -------- -------- -------|-
1: 10101010 10101010 10101010 1010101|0
2: 11001100 11001100 11001100 1100110|0
3: 11110000 11110000 11110000 1111000|0
4: 11111111 00000000 11111111 0000000|0
5: 11111111 11111111 00000000 0000000|0
```

The first thing to notice is that the binary values for 0 to 31 are represented in each column going from right to left (reading the bits in rows 1 through 5). This means that each vertical column is different from each other one (the important part). I put a vertical extra line between bit numbers 0 and 1 for a particular reason: Column 0 is useless because it has no bits set in it.

To perform error-correcting, we will bitwise-AND the received data bits against each EC bit's predefined mask, then compare the resulting parity to the EC bit. For any calculated parities discovered to not match, find the column in which *only* those bits are set. For example, if error-correcting bits 1, 4, and 5 are wrong when calculated from the received data value, then column #25--containing 1s in only those masks--must be the incorrect bit and can be corrected by flipping it. If only a single error-correcting bit is wrong, then the error is in that error-correcting bit. Here's an analogy to help you understand why this works:

> There are 32 identical boxes, with one containing a marble. Your task is to locate the marble using just an old-style scale (the kind with two balanced platforms to compare the weights of different objects) and you are only allowed 5 weighing attempts. The solution is fairly easy: you put 16 boxes on each side of the scale and the heavier side indicates which side the marble is on. Discarding the 16 boxes on the lighter side, you then weigh 8 and 8 boxes keeping the heavier, then 4 and 4, then 2 and 2, and finally locate the marble by comparing the weights of the last 2 boxes 1 to 1: the heaviest box contains the marble. You have completed the task in only 5 weighings of 32, 16, 8, 4, and 2 boxes.

Similarly, our bit patterns have divided up the boxes in 5 different groups. Going backwards, the fifth EC bit determines whether an error is on the left side or the right side. In our scenario with bit #25, it is wrong, so we know that the error bit is on the left side of the group (bits 16-31). In our next mask for EC bit #4 (still stepping backward), we only consider bits 16-31, and we find that the "heavier" side is the left one again, so we have narrowed down the bits 24-31. Following the decision tree downward and cutting the number of possible columns in half each time, by the time we reach EC bit 1 there is only 1 possible bit left--our "marble in a box".

Note: The analogy is useful, though not perfect: 1-bits are not represented by marbles--the erroring bit location is represented by the marble.

Now, some playing around with these masks and thinking how to arrange things will reveal that there is a problem: If we try to make all 31 bits data bits, then we need 5 more bits for EC. But how, then, will we tell if the EC bits themselves are wrong? Just a single EC bit wrong will incorrectly tell us that some data bit needs correction, and we'll wrongly flip that data bit. The EC bits have to somehow encode for themselves! The solution is to position the parity bits *inside* of the data, in columns from the bit patterns above where only one bit is set. This way, any data bit being wrong will trigger *two* EC bits to be wrong, making it so that if only one EC bit is wrong, we know it is wrong itself instead of it signifying a data bit is wrong. The columns that satisfy the one-bit condition are 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16. The data bits will be interleaved between these starting at position 2. (Remember, we are not using position 0 as it would never provide any information--none of our EC bits would be set at all).

Finally, adding one more bit for overall parity will allow detecting 2-bit errors and reliably correcting 1-bit errors, as we can then compare the EC bits to it: if the EC bits say something is wrong, but the parity bit says otherwise, we know there are 2 bits wrong and cannot perform correction. We can use the discarded bit #0 as our parity bit! In fact, now we are encoding the following pattern:

```
0: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

This gives us a final total of 6 Error-Checking and Correcting (ECC) bits. Extending the scheme of using different masks indefinitely looks like this:

```
32 bits - 6 ECC bits = 26 data
64 bits - 7 ECC bits = 57 data
128 bits - 8 ECC bits = 120 data
256 bits - 9 ECC bits = 247 data
512 bits - 10 ECC bits = 502 data
```

Now, if we are sure that we only will get a 1-bit error, we can dispense with the #0 parity bit, so we have the following:

```
31 bits - 5 ECC bits = 26 data
63 bits - 6 ECC bits = 57 data
127 bits - 7 ECC bits = 120 data
255 bits - 8 ECC bits = 247 data
511 bits - 9 ECC bits = 502 data
```

This is no change because we don't get any more data bits. Oops! 32 bytes (256 bits) as you requested cannot be error-corrected with a single byte, *even if we know we can have only a 1-bit error at worst, and we know the ECC bits will be correct* (allowing us to move them out of the data region and use them all for data). We need TWO more bits than we have--one must slide up to the next range of 512 bits, then leave out 246 data bits to get our 256 data bits. So that's one more ECC bit AND one more data bit (as we only have 255, exactly what Daniel told you).

**Summary:: You need 33 bytes + 1 bit to detect which bit flipped in the first 32 bytes.**

Note: if you are going to send 64 bytes, then you're under the 32:1 ratio, as you can error correct that in just 10 bits. But it's that in real world applications, the "frame size" of your ECC can't keep going up indefinitely for a few reasons: 1) The number of bits being worked with at once may be much smaller than the frame size, leading to gross inefficiencies (think ECC RAM). 2) The chance of being able to accurately correct a bit gets less and less, since the larger the frame, the greater the chance it will have more errors, and 2 errors defeats error-correction ability, while 3 or more can defeat even error-detection ability. 3) Once an error is detected, the larger the frame size, the larger the size of the corrupted piece that must be retransmitted.

Comment: Another way of figuring this is to figure that one needs a mapping from "received data" to "corrected data", such that any packet which is received correctly or with only one bit error will map to the original correct data.  For each possible 264-bit data packet, there are 265 ways it might be received such that that one should be able to recover: with all bits intact, with bit 0 flipped, with bit 1 flipped, etc.  Thus, the number of different data packets one can represent with 264 bits while being able to recover all single-bit errors is (2^264)/265.  Since there are 2^256 combinations...

Comment: ...of 256 bits, and since 2^256 is greater than (2^264)/265, that would imply that either there must be some combinations of 256 bits that cannot be represented, or else there must be some representable combinations which cannot be recovered in the presence of all possible single-bit errors.  Depending upon the nature of the data being stored, one of these might not pose a problem.  For example, if one knew that at most three of the top 4 bits in the original data can be set, there'd be no problem--there would then be only 15*(2^252) possible data packets, and that's less than (2^264)/265.

Comment: Thanks for the extra discussion. Did you find any errors in my information?

Comment: I think that looks correct, but it does seem a little overwhelming.  I think counting up the number of possible data packets and the number of ways they might be received is a simple and useful starting point.  Among other things, there are many real-world applications where one has a 32-byte packet but certain combinations of bits can be ruled out.  If one can rule out enough possibilities, one may be able to correct single-bit errors using only 8 bits of supplemental forward-error-correction data.

Comment: @supercat What you're saying is to either exclude bits, or shorten the length by re-encoding (aka compression)--to exploit inner knowledge of the meaning of the bits to not provide ECC data for combinations that are impossible. That sounds quite reasonable. But I was more interested in the general case of all the bits being equally important. :) I hope my answer was useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a whole byte instead of a bit, and you only need to detect errors, then the standard solution is to use a [cyclic redundancy check (CRC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). There are several well-known 8-bit CRCs to choose from.

A typical fast implementation of a CRC uses a table with 256 entries to handle a byte of the message at a time.  For the case of an 8 bit CRC this is a special case of Pearson's algorithm.

Comment: For good polynomials, look at [Koopman's CRC page](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/index.html). `0xe7` or `0x83` is optimal for most bit lengths, Unless you know you stand to benefit from a higher HD value for certain bit lengths.